# Set blur or gradient to text that is moved by overflow

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to blur some text or set a gradient on it when it is moved out of the div because of the overflow (scrolling)?

 It looks a little bit cut when I scroll in a div and the text gets out of the container.

At the end of the div you can see that the text is simply cutted of when it goes out of the div. The parent div of the one that contains the text has a **padding:25px;** and **background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);**.

@RMo UPDATE:
This is exactly what I want. Now the alignment fails a little bit. I have a container where I inject some content. This is the css of the container:

```
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

And this inside I have another div that has **overflow:auto;**.
So the structure is:

```
<div id="main" ng-view>
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="blur-top"></div>
    Lorem ipsum ...
    <div class="blur-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use **position:fixed;** on the blur classes. The gradient is not even displayed. When I use **position:relative;** then the gradient is there but of course it scrolls with the content because it is not fixed. How can I solve this?
And in general it looks like that the gradient does not match the color, even if I set it to the background. My result looks like this at the moment: [position:relative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjSTM.png)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qezzc9gg/5/

Comment: Please add your html and css code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/qezzc9gg/4/ here is a just example can you explain a bit more

Comment: @MostafaBaezid I also updated the fiddle to my current state: https://jsfiddle.net/qezzc9gg/5/

Comment: looks like you are currently facing screen overflowing-y also??

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/ghefa90g/ ] take a look is that helpful for you or not.

Comment: this did the trick! thanks a lot!

Comment: your welcome I added this as answer. HaPpY Coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the width from id #main which fix the screen overflowing-y and added border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px;  into blur-top and  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; into blur-bottom. which match the #main div border-radius. and also remove some extra css part those are unnecessary . And also thanks to @RMo who gives the prefect idea. . If any question ask me in comment. :) [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/ghefa90g/1/)

```css
#main {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.blur-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;

}

.blur-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;

}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
<div class="blur-top"></div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<div class="blur-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? The code should be self explanatory. Leave a comment if you need some extra explanation.

[A codepen example](http://codepen.io/RobMo/pen/qaoNqo)

**html**

```
    <div class="blur-top"></div>
      <article>
        <h1>Text with fadeout edges on top/bottom by RMo</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant... </p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant... </p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant... </p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant... </p>
      </article>
    <div class="blur-bottom"></div>
```

**css**

```
.blur-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.blur-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: please see my updated question. basically this is what I want to achieve but I currently have some troubles with the alignment ..

Comment: @pwolaq Yes, the alignment issues are caused by the fixed positioning. It can be solved by using absolute positioning (as pwolaq edited). Absolute positioning is basically the same as fixed positioning, except it doesn't place items in relation to the browser window, but to the first relative positioned ancestor. Do not forget to set position: relative on the parent div! PS: I might refine this idea someday, would be pretty cool to try and do this with pseudo elements instead of extra divs/html.